# How to resolve TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs' Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm working on Django forms however I'm getting this error

**TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'**

So what I do not understand is I get the error only when I include the email and the two passwords fields and this really does not make sense to me hence I fail to fix this error can I please get help to understand what is actually happening here and what is causing this error.

**CODE BELOW: forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField



class UserAccount(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',     'placeholder':'First Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Surname'}))
    phone = PhoneNumberField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Phone Number'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailField(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Password'}))
    verify_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'verify password'}))
```

I do not know if the views.py file and the html file will help fix this error please state and I shall gladly update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [**`EmailField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#emailfield) is *not* a widget. The standard widget for an `EmailField` is an [**`EmailInput`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#emailinput):

```
class UserAccount(forms.Form):
    # …
    email = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}
        )
    )
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `UserAccountForm` instead of
> <s>`UserAccount`</s>.

Comment: Oh okay thanks the solution you gave is right on the spot

Answer (score 1):

You assign **the form field [forms.EmailField(attrs={})](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield)** to **"widget"** which is wrong:

```py
class UserAccount(forms.Form):
    # ...
    email = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.EmailField(attrs={...}) # Wrong
    )
    # ...
```

So, instead, you need to assign **the widget [forms.EmailInput(attrs={})](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#emailinput)** to **"widget"** which is correct:

```py
class UserAccount(forms.Form):
    # ...
    email = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={...}) # Correct
    )
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailField(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}))
```

instead of

```
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}))
```

> not EmailField => EmailInput